# best way to check logs after Makefile command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, testing, makefile

One of my projects' Makefile runs a bunch of tests on a headless browser for the functional test step. Most of the test is for the front-end code, but i also check for any error/warning on the backend.

Currently, we are cleaning the web server log, running all the (very slow) tests, and then grepping the server log for any error or warning.

i was wondering if there was any way to have a listener parsing the log (e.g. `tail -f | grep`) starting on the background, and kill the make target if it detects any error/warning during the test run.

what i got so far was

1. start long lived grep in the background and store PID.
2. run tests.
3. check output of long lived grep
4. kill PID.
5. in case of any error, fail.

This only bought me the advantage that now i do not lose the server logs on my dev box every time, as i do not have to clean it every time. But i still have to wait a long time (minutes) for a failure that may have occurred in the very first one.

is there any solution for it?

Comment: Use something more flexible then `grep`? Like `awk` or insert-favorite-scripting-language that can run arbitrary commands on matches as they occur?

Comment: @EtanReisner that should be fine, i don't really care for grep or not. But it is still not clear how to capture a log message from awk or anything after make put it in background.

Comment: Hm? awk can directly execute commands as it processes its input and can exit whenever it needs to.

Comment: @EtanReisner Make relies on return value of commands it started to decide on failure or not. if i put one command on background to run others, i can't return a value. and that background program being able to start other commands won't help me. or i am not seeing how it would...

Comment: @gcb, I think you have a clear idea what to do. The technical solution is as you have described in 3rd paragraph. Your real problem is that you need more experience with the shell scripting. Or better - the Python/Perl/etc scripting.

Comment: @gcd, also check the `man stdbuf` and `grep --line-buffered`. (Could it be that you question is really about the long wait?)

Comment: @Dummy00001 i still can't see how to do that with stdbuffers.  i can forward it to a file, grep buffered, etc. but the problem is, how do i tell Make about a match on those things (file or background process) while Make has something else on the foreground?

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there was any way to have a listener parsing the log (e.g. `tail -f | grep`) starting on the background, and kill the make target if it detects any error/warning during the test run.

Have you tried doing it the simple straightforward way? Like this, for example:

```
# make is started somehow, e.g.:
make target >make-target.log 2>&1 &
PIDOFMAKE=$!
# we know its PID and the log file name

tail -f make-target.log | grep 'ERROR!' |
while read DUMMY; do
    # error was detected, kill the make:
    kill $PIDOFMAKE
    break
done
```

(Though it is not clear to me what OP is asking, I'm writing an answer since I can't put a lot of code into the comment.)

Comment: i do not care about make's output. i care about a log outside of the command. for example: i want to check `logs/apache.err` while, in the make file, running tests against a web application. it would be `tail -f logs/apache.err | grep ERROR` running while i run the tests `selenium test...`.